# Why do these JavaScript regular expression capture parenthesis snag entire line instead of the suffixes appended to a word?

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone please tell me WHY my simple expression doesn't capture the optional arbitrary length .suffix fragments following hello, matching complete lines?

Instead, it matches the ENTIRE LINE (hello.aa.b goodbye) instead of the contents of the capture parenthesis.

Using this code ([see JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gd7Z9/1/)):

```
//var line = "hello goodbye";            // desired: suffix null
//var line = "hello.aa goodbye";         // desired: suffix[0]=.aa
var line = "hello.aa.b goodbye";         // desired: suffix[0]=.aa suffix[1]=.b
var suffix = line.match(/^hello(\.[^\.]*)*\sgoodbye$/g);
```

I've been working on this simple expression for OVER three hours and I'm beginning to believe I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how capturing works: isn't there a "cursor" gobbling up each line character-by-character and capturing content inside the parenthesis ()?

Comment: Several reasons, including things like your asterisk is in the wrong place if you want 0 or more non-period/space chars, the period is in the capture group, etc.

Comment: Oh my, "OVER three hours"? In my day you'd work on a problem for a _week_ before considering that you were getting nowhere. This new generation is always in such a hurry.

Comment: Dave, thanks for pointing that out.  Ideally, I don't want the period in the capture group but it's okay if it is; I can't get a simple capture group to work let alone one that has nested parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally started from Perl and then PHP. When I started with JavaScript, I got stuck with this situation once myself.

In JavaScript, the GLOBAL match does NOT produce a multidimensional array. In other words, in GLOBAL match there is only match[0] (no sub-patterns).

Please note that suffix[0] matches the whole string.

Try this:

```
//var line = "hello goodbye";            // desired: suffix undefined
//var line = "hello.aa goodbye";         // desired: suffix[1]=.aa
var line = "hello.aa.b goodbye";         // desired: suffix[1]=.aa suffix[2]=.b

var suffix = line.match(/^hello(\.[^.]+)?(\.[^.]+)?\s+goodbye$/);
```

If you have to use a global match, then you have to capture the whole strings first, then run a second RegEx to get the sub-patterns.

Good luck
:)

**Update: Further Explanation**

If each string only has ONE matchable pattern (like `var line = "hello.aa.b goodbye";`)
then you can use the pattern I posted above (without the GLOBAL modifier)

If a sting has more than ONE matchable pattern, then look at the following:

```
// modifier g means it will match more than once in the string
// ^ at the start mean starting with, when you wan the match to start form the beginning of the string
// $ means the end of the string
// if you have ^.....$ it means the whole string should be a ONE match
var suffix = line.match(/^hello(\.[^.]+)?(\.[^.]+)?\s+goodbye$/g);


var line = 'hello.aa goodbye and more hello.aa.b goodbye and some more hello.cc.dd goodbye';

// no match here since the whole of the string doesn't match the RegEx
var suffix = line.match(/^hello(\.[^.]+)?(\.[^.]+)?\s+goodbye$/);

// one match here, only the first one since it is not a GLOBAL match (hello.aa goodbye)
// suffix[0] = hello.aa goodbye
// suffix[1] = .aa
// suffix[2] = undefined
var suffix = line.match(/hello(\.[^.]+)?(\.[^.]+)?\s+goodbye/);

// 3 matches here (but no sub-patterns), only a one dimensional array with GLOBAL match in JavaScript
// suffix[0] = hello.aa goodbye
// suffix[1] = hello.aa.b goodbye
// suffix[2] = hello.cc.dd goodbye
var suffix = line.match(/hello(\.[^.]+)?(\.[^.]+)?\s+goodbye/g);
```

I hope that helps.
:)

Comment: thank you!  There is a nuance I don't understand.  I *did* have to implement two steps as you suggested.  Once I have the correct line, the statement at the end of this comment DOES properly match the suffixes since I  then was able to leave out the ^$ symbols.  It's GLOBAL yet it does match MORE than match[0].  Please help me as that contradicts your second sentence. Three SO answers are telling me the same thing yet I sincerely don't understand! line.match /(\.[^\.\s]+)/g

Comment: OK...I will update my post with more explanation in a little while

Comment: I was getting the global(g) flag mixed up with the number of intended captures.

Answer (score 0):

inside ()
please do not look for . and then some space , instead look for . and some characters and finally outside () look for that space

Answer (score 0):

A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations.

```
var suffix = line.match(/^hello((\.[^\.]*)*)\sgoodbye$/g);
if (suffix !== null)
    suffix = suffix[1].match(/(\.[^\.\s]*)/g)
```

and I recommand [regex101 site](http://regex101.com/#javascript).

Comment: I got the match method to return all iterations if the ^ and $ symbols are omitted: I don't know how to reconcile that with your answer.  Any ideas?  line.match /(\.[^\.\s]+)/g

Answer (score 0):

Using the global flag with the `match` method doesn't return any capturing groups. See the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.10).

Although you use `()*` it's only one capturing group. The `*` only defines that the content has to be matched 0 or more time before the space comes.

As @EveryEvery has pointed out you can use a two-step approach.

Comment: I haven't read the spec yet, but I got the match method to return capturing groups when the ^$ symbols are left out.  I'm really confused because this works; how could it?: line.match /(\.[^\.\s]+)/g

Comment: @PeteAlvin `"hello.aa.b goodbye".match(/(\.[^\.\s]+)/g)` returns `[".aa", ".b"]`. That's not the capturing groups, but the matches.